# sp2010 to sp2016 and reporting services viewer in sharepoint 2016 error

Tags: reporting-services, migration, report-builder

[image: try to generate the report]I made a migration from sharepoint 2010 to 2016, and I'm having a problem, I'm using reporting services and I want to visualize reports from the browser without using report builder but, I cannot do it, when I try to generate the report it launches me the following error *"Cannot get the 'ValidateInputs' property of null or undefined reference. RSViewerPage.aspx"*

Comment: have you correctly installed Reporting Services on SP16 and SP16 SQL?

Comment: it's necessary to install it in the sp2016 SQL?

Comment: i am only asking you, if you have correctly set the SQL

Comment: yes, always we do it like that, in sp10 and sp13 that function work without problems, just in sp16 we have this problem

Comment: verify you have installed it correctly https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36240.sharepoint-2016-install-reporting-service-in-farm.aspx or https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-reporting-services-sharepoint-mode?view=sql-server-2016

Comment: I created a new web application and works correctly the reports, apparently the migration is the problem

Comment: ok, good to know.

Comment: NT:  only with the web application that we migrate we have this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check is debugging is off in your web.config, it should be like this

```
<SafeMode...... CallStack="true">
<customErrors mode="On">
<compilation batch="false" debug="false">
```